# Python: AStar Pathfinder algorithm

Tags: python, pathfinding, a-star

Traverse through any binary array using the Manhattan distance by giving a start node location and an end node location. The neighbor() method gives the neighbors next to the x,y coordinates that are == to 0, the f_value() method assigns a value to the neighboring nodes based on a heuristic, and the path() method tells the algorithm which neighbor it should move to, based on the f_values.

Any ways I can make this algorithm more efficient, specifically with loops/modules?

Also, any tips on the pythonic nature of my code would be appreciated as well.

```
    '''
    @author: BenNicholl
    '''   
      #  please cite algorithm if used
      #  Algorithm changes the integer values of the grid array being used

    import numpy as np

    nmap = np.array([
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

    class AStar():

        def __init__(self, grid, x, y, goal_x, goal_y)    :
            self.grid = grid
            self.initial_x = x  #  never changes
            self.initial_y = y  #  never changes
            self.x = self.initial_x  #  does change
            self.y = self.initial_y  #  does change
            self.goal_x = goal_x  # never changes
            self.goal_y = goal_y  #  never changes
            self.neighbors = []
            self.neighbor()

        def neighbor(self):
            #  if x and y == goal_x and goal_y, algo is complete
            if self.x == self.goal_x and self.y == self.goal_y:
                print('your done')
                return 'your done'

            #  sets the x and y coordinates to 1 so they are not revisited
            self.grid[self.x][self.y] = 1 

            #  the below if statements give you the coordinates of 
            #  the neighbors that have a value of 0            
            if self.x > 0:  #  if X will be on the grid if it moves UP 1 node
                if self.grid[self.x-1] [self.y] == 0:
                    self.neighbors.append([self.x - 1, self.y])  

            if self.x < self.grid.shape[0] - 1:  #  if X will be on the grid if it moves DOWN 1 node
                if self.grid[self.x+1][self.y] == 0: 
                    self.neighbors.append([self.x+1,self.y]) 

            if self.y > 0: #  If Y will be on grid if it moves LEFT 1 node
                if self.grid[self.x][self.y - 1] == 0:
                    self.neighbors.append([self.x, self.y - 1]) #  

            if self.y < self.grid.shape[1] - 1: #  If Y will be on grid if it moves RIGHT 1 node
                if self.grid[self.x][self.y + 1] == 0:
                    self.neighbors.append([self.x, self.y + 1]) 

            self.f_value()

        #  this method gives you the f_value off all the neighbors    
        def f_value(self):
            h_values = []
            g_values = []  

            #  calculate distance from the neighboring X, Y to end X, Y value using Manhattan distance 
            for i in self.neighbors:     
                x_distance = abs(i[0] - self.goal_x)  
                y_distance = abs(i[1] - self.goal_y)  
                h_value = (x_distance + y_distance)
                h_values.append(h_value)

            #  calculate distance from the neighboring X, Y to the initial X, Y values   
            for i in self.neighbors:
                x_distance = abs(i[0] - self.initial_x)  
                y_distance = abs(i[1] - self.initial_y)
                g_value = (x_distance + y_distance)
                g_values.append(g_value)

            #  add g_value and h_value to calculate f_value
            self.f_values = [h + g for h, g in zip(h_values, g_values)]
            self.path()

        #  gets the lowest f_value, then pops that f_value and corresponding neighbor
        #  the neighbor always has the same index as the f_values
        def path(self):

            for coordinate, i in enumerate(self.f_values):
                if i <= min(self.f_values):
                    value = i
                    index = coordinate 

            self.x = self.neighbors[index][0]        
            self.y = self.neighbors[index][1]

            print('f_values:', self.f_values)
            print('neighbors:', self.neighbors)  
            print('x:', self.x)
            print('y:', self.y)

            self.neighbors.pop(index)
            self.f_values.pop(index)

            self.neighbor()
```

Answer (score 2):

For the pythonic ways, I'd recommend using `"""` for documenting functions and methods.

Instead of:

```
#  this method gives you the f_value off all the neighbors    
def f_value(self):
    ...
```

I'd go with

```
def f_value(self):
    '''
    This method gives you the f_value off all the neighbors. 
    '''
    ...
```

And I recommend you read [this link](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/documentation/) on why docstring is different from block comments and how you can get the best of them.

This allow you to write things like:

```
def return_6(self):
    '''
    This method return 6. 
    >>>return_6()
    6
    '''
    return 6
```

Then run automatised test using your docstring or writing this:

```
def random_number_generator(arg1, arg2):
    """
    Summary line.

    Extended description of function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg1 : int
        Description of arg1
    arg2 : str
        Description of arg2

    Returns
    -------
    int
        Description of return value

    """
    return 42
```

And then use tools like [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) to build your documentation with [ReadTheDoc](https://readthedocs.org/) for example.